# Library not found for -lFolly

Tags: xcode, react-native, folly

After updating react-native from version 0.63.2 to 0.66.1, i get the following error in Xcode when i try to build my app.

**library not found for -lFolly**

I've tried running `pod install` and cleaning the build folder.
My Library Search Paths look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAJr5.png) for both release and debug.

Comment: I am also facing same issue. Can you please let me know if you already found the solution?

Comment: Same here, please tell the solution if available.

Comment: @SaifAliKhan you can refer to my answer

Answer (score 1):

Delete libFolly.a file from Xcode>Targets>General and clean DerivedData, run again. Maybe you can face with other problems but if you don't use folly file in your pods it will work. I hope it works for you too.

[image]

Comment: there is no such file in the specified section but I am still getting error? What else I can check?

Comment: Dude thank you!! I was going MAD because I tried everything but this.

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with this issue. Finally this solution resolved the issue.

> I had the two copies of files in the codebase. Deleting one copy helped code to build successfully

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53417764/8364900

```
<project name>/ios/<project name>.xcworkspace/contents.xcworkspacedata
```

The above location may have reference to multiple copies of your project. If so delete one copy then run the project.